# Differentiating between "real" avatar image and "broken link" image pulled directly from Jira url

Tags: ruby, image, jira

I have a ruby function that connects to Jira and returns a user's avatar image encoded in base64 (see "requestImage" below). I have no way of differentiating between a "broken link" image received when the user has not set an image for their profile, and an "actual" image when they have.

The values are indistinguishable in base64, and even more indistinguishable previous to their encoding.

```
def requestImage(d_url)
 username = JIRA_USER_CONFIG[:username]
 password = JIRA_USER_CONFIG[:password]
 query = CGI::parse(URI::parse(d_url).query)
 url = query['d'][0]
 url = URI.unescape(url)
 uri = URI.parse(url)
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

 if uri.scheme == 'https'
   http.use_ssl =
   http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
 end
 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
 if !username.nil? && !username.empty?
   request.basic_auth(username, password)
 end
 response = http.request(request).body
 "data:image/png;base64, "+Base64.encode64(response)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

I realized the "broken link" image is a failure to render an SVG. I modified "data:image/png;base64, " to "data:image/svg+xml;base64, ". This resolved the issue.